# Omitting the second part of the ternary operator

Tags: php, conditional-operator

Given the following expression:

```
$att['menutext'] = isset($attrib_in['i_menu_text']) ? : $this->getID();
```

If it evaluates to true, will `$att['menutext']` be set to `true` or `$this->getID()`?

Comment: This won't execute, it's invalid syntax. `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' on line X`

Comment: Not in PHP 5.3. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Comment: That explains why it didn't work on 5.2.5 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just the same as the following

`$att['menutext'] = isset($attrib_in['i_menu_text']) ? true : $this->getID();`

Comment: Just to clarify for passersby, this shortcut version of the ternery operator returns whatever the condition evaluates to, not just Boolean `true` in every instance. In this case, the condition would evaluate to `true`. But if you had `$foo = 42 ? : false;`, `$foo` would be assigned `42`.

Comment: I am particularly impressed with the fact that this answer and comment actually answered the question I **meant** to ask as well as the one I **did** ask

Comment: This answer is incorrect, there's no `isset` implied.

Answer (score 15):

According to [this reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary):

> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the
>   ternary operator. Expression *expr1 ?: expr3* returns *expr1* if
>   *expr1* evaluates to TRUE, and *expr3* otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in version 5.3+ the middle expression is optional and returns true.

```
$a = (true ? : 1); // $a evaluates to true.
$a = (false ? : 1); // $a evaluates to 1.
```

Comment: Just to clarify for passersby, this shortcut version of the ternery operator returns whatever the condition evaluates to, not just Boolean `true` in every instance. In this case, the condition would evaluate to `true`. But if you had `$foo = 42 ? : false;`, `$foo` would be assigned `42`.

Comment: Is there a way to use first expression as a result of the second or third? Like `$db->get('id', 'users', 'id', $id) ? previous_query : anything_else`. Now you have to write `$db->get('id', 'users', 'id', $id) ? $db->get('id', 'users', 'id', $id) : anything_else`. Which makes two requests to the db. You could save it to vars before that but it's all not what I mean. Not possible?

Answer (score 1):

never tested before, but its quite easy to test:

```
<?php var_dump(TRUE ? : 'F'); ?>
```

and its says: bool(true)

Answer (score 0):

This won't execute, it's invalid syntax for **PHP < 5.3**.

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' on line X`

If you want the value to be set to true, then use true:

```
$att['menutext'] = isset($attrib_in['i_menu_text']) ? true : $this->getID();
```

Or it may be more likely that you want:

```
$att['menutext'] = isset($attrib_in['i_menu_text']) ? $attrib_in['i_menu_text'] : $this->getID();
```

Comment: Since PHP 7.0, you can simplify `$att['menutext'] = isset($attrib_in['i_menu_text']) ? $attrib_in['i_menu_text'] : $this->getID();` into `$att['menutext'] = $attrib_in['i_menu_text'] ?? $this->getID();`.